# Convert maven to gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have a project in maven. I want to convert project to gradle project how convert this code maven to code gradle:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.functions</groupId>
                <artifactId>function-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <functionTarget>org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.gcp.GcfJarLauncher</functionTarget>
                    <port>8080</port>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: isn't this answers your question? https://howtodoinjava.com/gradle/convert-maven-project-to-gradle-project/

Comment: Why do you want to convert the project?

Answer (score 2):

First install `Gradle` on your machine.

Now, go to your maven project’s root directory and execute command:

```
gradle init
```

Please note that `gradle init` automatically detects the `pom.xml` and creates a `gradle` build with the `Java` and `maven plugin` loaded. It means that *existing Maven dependencies are automatically converted and added to your gradle build file*.

So that the `build.gradle` file will be automatically created thanks to the `gradle init` command.And now your project is using gradle

Answer (score 0):

I've never used function framework, however when it comes to plugin translation, these are pieces of code usually written by the maintainers of the framework, and usually they want to provide plugins for both maven and gradle.

Indeed in the documentation of the project, there is section for maven:

[See Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-java#configuration-in-pomxml)

And also for gradle:

[See Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-java#running-a-function-with-gradle)

It looks like they offer to register the task in gradle, so its the best you can do with the existing state of the project, so its the way to go I believe

Comment: I am following spring cloud https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-function/3.0.7.RELEASE/reference/html/gcp.html, but they dont have a sample for gradle, how do I config it in gradle?